# Showing $f,g$ integrable

Tags: analysis

I am solving the inequality below:

$$\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)\right)^2 \leq \left(\int_a^bf(x)^2dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_a^bg(x)^2dx\right)$$

I was given the following hint:

$$\int_a^b\left(\int_a^b(f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x))^2dx\right)dy$$

I didn't use the hint and instead came up with this:

$$\left(\int_a^bf^2(x)g^2(y)dxdy\right)^2=\left(\int_a^bg^2(y)\int_a^bf^2(x)dx\right)dy=\left(\int_a^bf^2(x)dx\int_a^bg^2(x)dx\right)^2$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just expand the square in the hint.

Comment: The expression in the hint is clearly greater than zero. Expand out the bracket and you should get to the required answer quickly. You thing that you "came up with" isn't a tight  inequality so I'm not sure where it's going to get you.

Comment: Ive expanded the square in the hint, but I still cant get the answer.

Comment: The expansion is $\int_a^b(\int_a^bf^2(x)g^2(y)-2f(x)g(y)f(y)g(x)-g^2(x)f^2(y))dxdy$

Comment: should be $(\dots+g^2(x)f^2(y))dxdy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the hint since you seem to be having some trouble, after expanding we get

$$\begin{align*}
0\leq\int_a^b\left(\int_a^b(f^2(x)g^2(y)-2f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)+f^2(y)g^2(x))dx\right)dy
\end{align*}\tag{$*$}$$

Now, since $x,y$ are dummy variables, then
$$\int_a^b\int_a^b f^2(x)g^2(y)dxdy=\left(\int_a^bg^2(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_a^bf^2(x)dx\right)=\int_a^b\int_a^bf^2(y)g^2(x)dxdy$$
and $$\int_a^b\int_a^bf(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)dxdy=\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\int_a^bf(y)g(y)dy=\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 $$
so $(*)$ simplifies to $$0\leq  2\left(\int_a^bf^2(x)dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_a^bg^2(x)dx\right)-2\left(\int_a^bf(x)g(x)dx\right)^2 $$
which gives the desired result.